# How do I tell if Windows 10 was a fresh install or upgrade from 7/8?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

Is there a reliable way to determine the OS upgrade history leading to Windows 10 or if it was a fresh install?

Comment: Look out for a `Windows.old` folder on your boot drive. If that folder is present, check whether it contains data from an earlier Windows version or Windows 10.

Comment: @GiantTree that's a temporary way to tell, since that folder is deleted after 30 days. I'm unaware of any other method to tell whether it was an upgrade or clean installation.

Comment: look for the value **MediaBootInstall** under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Setup/OOBE/**. If MediaBootInstall = 1, WIndows was installed via ISO/DVD. If MediaBootInstall = 0, the Windows was an upgrade

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is an excellent tutorial on Ten Forums pertaining to a separate topic:

[How to Move Users Profile Folder to another Location in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1964-users-folder-move-location-windows-10-a.html)

Within that tutorial, the author says the following:

> We need to edit Windows registry to "fool" Windows to think this is a clean install instead of an upgrade. To do this open the **Registry Editor** (WIN + R, type regedit, hit Enter), browse to key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup**
>
> Delete both the **DWORD** Upgrade (right pane) and **KEY** Upgrade (left pane), see screenshot.

The author's subsequent screen shot displays the appropriate entries in the registry:

[image: Delete Upgrade DWORD]

The following area within the registry seems to be the key to determining whether or not a Windows 10 install was an upgrade:

> **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup**

In order to prove this theory, I first initiated a clean install of Windows 10 on my test machine and scrutinized the same area of the registry.  The `Upgrade` key is notably absent:

[image: HKLM System Setup]

Next, I used another machine for a clean install of Windows 7 and then performed an in-place upgrade to Windows 10.  Looking at the same area of the registry, I saw the following:

[image: Registry - Upgrade Setup]

Notice that the `Upgrade` key is present, along with a pertinent `Source OS` key.  If we take a closer look at the `Source OS` key we see the following:

[image: Registry - Upgrade Source OS]

You can clearly see **Windows 7 Enterprise** listed as the value for the `ProductName` related to the `Source OS` key.

Community feedback led to additional research.  Taking a look at another machine that was originally setup with a clean install of the RTM baseline of Windows 10 (version 1507), we see the following:

[image: Registry Upgrade - Source OS 1511]

Although this computer's OS was configured via a clean install, the `Upgrade` key is still present.  However, when we examine each `Source OS` key we can see that the dates for each update correspond to approximately the same time frame as the first two major Windows 10 feature update releases: versions 1511 and 1607.  Also, the value for the `ProductName` shows **Windows 10 Pro**, even on the oldest `Source OS` key.  The newer `Source OS` key features an additional clue:

[image: Registry Upgrade - Source OS 1607]

The latest update shows a `ReleaseId` value of **1511**, indicating the precise version of Windows 10 that was being utilized prior to the update.

**Based upon what we have seen, we can draw the following conclusions**:

- The `HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup` registry key allows us to determine if Windows 10 was originally setup with a clean install, or an upgrade.
- If the `Upgrade` key is missing, it was definitely a clean install.
- If the `Upgrade` key is there, it could have been generated by a traditional Windows upgrade (from either Windows 7 or Windows 8.x), or it may have been created during a major Windows 10 feature update (e.g., versions 1511 and 1607).
- If the `Upgrade` key is there, you need to inspect the `Source OS` keys.
- The oldest `Source OS` key will reveal the original operating system within the corresponding `ProductName` value:  if it's a flavor of Windows 7 or Windows 8, it was an upgrade.  If it is a variant of Windows 10, it was a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

As posted by Magicandre1981 in the comments:

Look for the value MediaBootInstall under

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Setup/OOBE/.

If MediaBootInstall = 1, WIndows was installed via ISO/DVD.

If MediaBootInstall = 0, the Windows was an upgrade

Comment: I've checked multiple Windows 10 1511 and 1607 installs, and none of them have a MediaBootInstall key in the OOBE branch.  They have an "InstallType", and so far it's been either 4 or 5, but I haven't been able to discern its use/meaning yet...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, I took the time to check two machines on my home network in an attempt to verify this.  Both of them were setup with a clean install of Windows 10 1607 back in late January: one is x64, the other is x86.  Each of them actually does have the `MediaBootInstall` DWORD related to the `OOBE` key, but the value is `0` within both. In my experience, both Magicandre1981 and Moab have been a terrific source of reliable Windows answers, so I have no doubt that this was probably true at some point in time. However, the ongoing evolution of Windows 10 seems to have overridden this answer.

Comment: Just installed Win10 (20H2) to the newly formatted SSD and the `MediaBootInstall` dword is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Products = Get-ItemProperty -Name ProductName -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\SETUP\Source OS*" | select Productname -Unique
if ($Products -like '*7*')
{
WRITE-HOST Upgraded
}
ELSE
{
Write-Host Fresh Install
}
```